# How to trim multiple videos and position them to specific position using -filter_complex?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

How do I mix several videos and have them not overlap each other?
I need to use -filter_complex as I cram many more commands there and seems weird how when I trim video its frames remain and overlap with the other video. I also use tpad to paint the video black where it supposed to be cut but it just makes black images to overlap with other videos instead.

How do I trim and position videos with mix and make sure their frames do not overlap in result?
Here's the version vithout tpad

`./ffmpeg.exe -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=start=0:end=5[t0];[1]trim=start=5:end=10[t1];[t0][t1]mix=inputs=2" ./output.mp4`

It produces such overlapping frames
[image]

When adding tpad overlapping changes to mix of frame and black image

`./ffmpeg.exe -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=start=0:end=5[t0];[1]trim=start=5:end=10,setpts=PTS-5/TB,tpad=start_duration=5:start_mode=add:color=black@0x00[t1];[t0][t1]mix=inputs=2" ./output.mp4`

[image]

The alpha in tpad doesn't seem to do anything either.

**UPD:**

Thanks to Sark's answer I figured how to achieve it using a complex script to generate a command for concat filter. But the result is still quite clunky and requires additional inputs for generating empty spaces in case the videos should have a black space in between or to the sides.

Here's how it works:

1. Sort inputs by timelineTime+trimStart. Order is important in concat.
2. Add black color generator as input.
3. Insert black color for each empty space.
4. Reset PTS after each trim where start > 0.

Here's an example of dividing 1 video into two 5 second parts which play with 5 second black space in between.

`./ffmpeg.exe -i input1.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=c=black:s=1920x1080" -filter_complex "[0]trim=0:5[t0];[1]trim=0:5[t1];[0]trim=5:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[t2];[t0][t1][t2]concat=n=3" -an output.mp4`

Is there a way to do it easier?

Comment: It can be achieved with a single code, but it might make more sense to first trim each video clip, then, once you have all your clips, just concatenate them. Concatenation requires no further encoding, so will not affect the quality.

Comment: could you show an example of this single code solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, `[0:0]` is the video stream of the first input. `[0:1]` is the audio stream of the first input. We use `atrim` to trim the audio to match the trimmed video. `n=` is the number of inputs (not streams). `v=1` & `a=1` represent the number of output video and audio streams, these are then mapped to the same output file.

*Note: Start and End are not required for `trim`/`atrim` filters, just separate values with a colon.*

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex ^
[0:0]trim=0:3[outv0];[0:1]atrim=0:3[outa0];^
[1:0]trim=0:3[outv1];[1:1]atrim=0:3[outa1];^
[outv0][outa0][outv1][outa1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a] -map [v] -map [a] out.mp4
```

You can apply additional filtering to either/both inputs, prior to trimming and concatenating, by changing line two with the following, which desaturates the first input.

```
[0:0]eq=saturation=0[VS];^
[VS]trim=0:3[outv0];[0:1]atrim=0:3[outa0];^
```

Alternatively, you can filter the concatenated video stream as follows.

```
[outv0][outa0][outv1][outa1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a];[v]eq=saturation=0[v1] -map [v1] -map [a] out.mp4
```

EDIT.

To add 5 secs duration of black frames between clips, the following can be used.

Note: `setpts` after each trim filter can often resolve playback timing issues that may arise.

```
 ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black:1920*1080:d=5 -filter_complex ^
 [0]trim=0:5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[00];^
 [1]trim=0:5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[11];^
 [00][2][11]concat=n=3 -an out.mp4
```

Comment: thanks for responding. From what I understand I must provide inputs for concat in specific order for it to work. Is it possible to make concat work based on trim start/end params instead as I don't always know the order or is there some other way to change order based on desired time instead? Audio isn't important. I add it from separate inputs later on.

Comment: You're looking at a much more complex approach. Determining what should be input where is also beyond the basics of the concat filter. Maybe possible with some form of additional programming implimented. Way beyond my knowledge....You would need to be more explicit in what you are trying to do for someone to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I updated the question based on what I learned from your answer. I kind of achieved what I wanted by using additional coding and manipulating PTS/black screen. Do you think it's possible improve my current command?

Comment: If it works, it works, but...have edited my reply to show how I would approach it. Not significantly different. This produces two five second clips with five seconds of black between them.